# SQL: Avg time difference (DD:MM:HH:SS) between two dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to know the avg time between two times.  I want to write this by user name.

Here is an example:

```
Start of time   end of time user name
12/20/12        1/1/13  1
12/31/12        1/1/13  2
12/31/12        1/1/13  3
1/1/13          1/1/13  2
1/1/13          1/1/13  3
1/1/13          1/1/13  1
1/1/13          1/1/13  2
1/1/13          1/1/13  3
1/1/13          1/4/13  3
9/14/12         1/1/13  2
1/1/13          1/1/13  2
1/1/13          1/1/13  1
```

We have three users,

```
Username: 1
Username: 2
Username: 3
```

These 3 users worked started a task at some time (start of time) and end the task at some time (end of time).

I want to know the avg time consumed by these users?>

Could help write me query?.

Comment: What is the datatype of fields?

and will date contains HH:MM:SS??

Comment: Can you provide desired results for the sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have proper date format for our time column, and no explicit conversion needed for your table. Here is query to average:

```
select avg(avgs)/60/60/24 as Average from
     (select avg(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,star_time))) as avgs 
FROM t group by user)as res;
```

if you can provide more info, we can clear your problem.

For Demo I created, Click: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc42b/10)